# Trying to include an "or" in a case on mysql - Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, case, operand

I'm trying to include an "OR" clause in a CASE but I keep getting

> "Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Here's a sample of the query.

```
       select [...],
            CASE  
                when category1.Category1Name in (...) or category1.Category1Name like (...) then 'L-ACCESSORIES'
                when[...]
            end as 'Style'
       from [...]
```

If someone could shed some like on this it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Update: using 'or' instead of a comma-separated list in the 'like' bit seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this syntax completely worked on mysql

```
SELECT OrderID, Quantity,
CASE
    WHEN Quantity like 3 or quantity like 100 THEN "The quantity is either 3 or 100"

    ELSE "The quantity is something else"
END
FROM OrderDetails;
```

but when i used ***in*** instead of ***like*** it didn't work so the issue is not with or it's with ==> in . each case must be closed as well

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely coming from your `like` statement. It can only contain 1 value. If you write

```
like(1,2)
```

you will get this error.

All other operations should work in `mysql`.

Comment: This was the issue. Replacing commas with 'or' has worked just fine.
Cheers!